# Show selected rows based on status of task in the Task index page.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a dashboard in which I'm displaying details about the tasks based on its status (e.g. status: 0 means Task-Assigned status: 1 means Task-Taken), If user clicks on Task-Assigned link, then it should redirect to task index page, but displaying only the task which have status: 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The straightforward way is to add a status url param (which would go in your link) . Then tasks controller simply needs to filter tasks by that param (you could add a scope to your task model 'by_status' which performs this query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query string parameter to pass `status` in your `link_to` helper.

In your view file you can write following code -

```
<%= link_to "Task-Assigned", your_controller_path(status: 0) %>
<%= link_to "Task-Taken", your_controller_path(status: 1) %>
```

In your controller file you can write following code -

```
def method_name
  if params[:status].blank?
    tasks  = Task.all 
  else status specific tasks#
    tasks = Task.where(status: params[:status]) 
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, It helped but what if I still want to display all the task regardless of their status, how do I incorporate that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397061/to-display-time-spent-by-user-on-all-tasks-daily

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: need help with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988316/current-users-id-to-be-selected-by-default-in-select-tag