# To display time spent by user on all tasks daily

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I want to display how much time a single user spends on all tasks in a day.

Currently I'm using this query to display the time spent by all the users on all tasks daily:

```
TaskTimeTracker.group("year(created_at)").group("month(created_at)").group("day(created_at)").sum("time_spent")
```

These are the Schema Information of models I have used.

```
#Table name: tasks

#id              :integer          not null, primary key
#name            :string(255)
#description     :text(65535)
#due_date        :string(255)
#status          :integer
#priority        :integer
#project_id      :integer
#user_id         :integer
#created_at      :datetime         not null
#updated_at      :datetime         not null
#estimated_time  :datetime
#start_time      :datetime
#completion_time :datetime
#parent_task_id  :integer
#task_type       :string(255)
#author_id       :integer
#slug            :string(255)

#Indexes

#index_tasks_on_project_id  (project_id)
#index_tasks_on_slug        (slug) UNIQUE
#index_tasks_on_user_id     (user_id)

#Table name: task_time_trackers

#id          :integer          not null, primary key
#description :text(65535)
#time_spent  :float(24)
#created_at  :datetime         not null
#updated_at  :datetime         not null
#task_id     :integer
#created_by  :string(255)

#Indexes

#index_task_time_trackers_on_task_id  (task_id)


class TaskTimeTracker < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    validates :description,presence:true
    validates :time_spent,presence:true
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  attr_accessor :estimated_time_field, :prev_user_id
  validate :due_date_validation

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :task_type, use: [:slugged,:finders]

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :worked_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :logs, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  has_many :subtasks, class_name: "Task", :foreign_key => :parent_task_id
  belongs_to :parent_task, class_name: "Task" 
  has_many :task_time_trackers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: you need to fetch whole the tasks done by single user and than do sum of that time

Comment: Could you also add your models and in what context are you using this query

Comment: I'm using this query for timesheet.

Comment: Would still be very useful to see your models. Also do you have author table/model. Please post it as well

Comment: no, there is no author table or model

Comment: Where are you getting author_id from then? That's task_time_trackers then?

Comment: author_id is just to check who created that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to get the desired result

u_id = params[:u_id]

```
TaskTimeTracker.joins(:task).where( task_time_trackers: { user_id: u_id}).where("(task_time_trackers.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)",Date.current.beginning_of_month, Date.current.end_of_month ).group("task_time_trackers.task_id").group("DAY(task_time_trackers.created_at)").sum("time_spent")
```

It will create a HASH.