# Show current User's data and it's name in select tag

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to display the current user's (manager) data based on params value passed through navbar and it's name in select tag, User has two role ('user', 'manager') or enum role (0 , 1).
This is the link I have given in navbar -

```
%li= link_to 'Timesheet', is_manager? ? timesheet_path(user_id: current_user.id) : timesheet_path, class: navlink_class('timesheets')
```

But in the controller it is getting complicated as the queries which I have used are these -

```
    @begin_date = params[:begin_date].present? ? Date.parse(params[:begin_date]) : Date.today.beginning_of_month
    @end_date = params[:end_date].present? ? Date.parse(params[:end_date]) : Date.today.end_of_month
    begin_datetime = @begin_date.beginning_of_day 
    end_datetime = @end_date.end_of_day 
    @user_tasks = Task.joins(:task_time_trackers).where("(task_time_trackers.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)",begin_datetime, end_datetime ).distinct.order("id ASC")
    user_trackers = TaskTimeTracker.joins(:task).where("(task_time_trackers.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)",begin_datetime, end_datetime )
    u_id = nil
    u_id = params[:u_id] if (params[:u_id] && params[:u_id] != 'all')
    u_id = current_user.id if current_user.role == 'user'
    unless u_id.nil? 
      @user_tasks = @user_tasks.where( task_time_trackers: { user_id: u_id})
      user_trackers = user_trackers.where( task_time_trackers: { user_id: u_id})
    end
```

And finally the select tag which I have used -

```
select_tag(:u_id, options_for_select(User.user_for_select(current_user), selected: params[:u_id]), class: "input-sm form-control", onchange: "this.form.submit();")
```

User Model -

```
      class << self
        def user_for_select(user)
          self
            .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{user.id} THEN 'Me' ELSE name END AS name, id")
            .unshift(['All', 'all'])
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the result, in the navbar made this change -

```
- if is_manager?
  %li= link_to 'Timesheet', timesheet_path(u_id: current_user.id) 
- else
  %li= link_to 'Timesheet', timesheet_path
```

and in the select tag this change -

```
select_tag(:u_id, options_for_select(User.user_for_select(current_user), params[:u_id]), class: "input-sm form-control", onchange: "this.form.submit();")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need load current_user in select list. But you can customize the selection in user model as the following:

```
def user_for_select(user)
  self
    .where(id: user.id)
    .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{user.id} THEN 'Me' ELSE name END AS name, id")
  end
end
```

**Edit depend on comment:**

Add the following method in user model:

```
def is_manager?
   self.role == "manager"
end
```

Then update selection as the following:

```
def user_for_select(user)
  if user.is_manager?
      self
        .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{user.id} THEN 'Me' ELSE name END AS name, id")
        .unshift(['All', 'all'])
  else
       self
         .where(id: user.id)
         .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{user.id} THEN 'Me' ELSE name END AS name, id")
  end
end
```

Comment: There are two roles for user's user and manager, manager can select any user or all the users, I'm using this in timesheet, so by default it loads all the records for all users, so I want it to load it's timesheet first, then he can select whether he wants to see all the users all just one particular, I'm also adding the query which I have used for this record generation.